# Downsides of fragmented arrays for dynamic byte storage

Tags: java, arrays

The default ByteArrayOutputStream seems a rather wasteful implementation and I was wondering if there is any specific reason for this. First off it keeps 1 fixed array in the backend. If that is full, it creates a new array and copies the old array into it (more memory + more overhead). Then if you do toByteArray() it actually copies the array again.

Byte buffers are nice but also fixed in size, they merely offer a few on a single array, nothing more.

I was wondering if it would be interesting to create a class (or if it already exists, please point me towards it) that uses one or more backing arrays. Instead of duplicating the array each time to expand, it just adds a new backing array. To read you can easily create a interface like inputstream while you can expose an interface like outputstream for writing

Any feedback on whether such a thing already exists and if not: why? Does it have some downside I'm not seeing?

Comment: "I was wondering if it would be interesting to create a class ..." -  Yes it would be interesting.  Off you go!

Answer (score 2):

**This is actually a great idea, especially for large data.**

You can quicky run into **memory problems when allocating huge arrays on the heap**, as they need contiguous free memory to be allocated. We once had such a situation when we often allocated byte arrays with 10-50MB size, and ran into `OutOfMemoryException`s, not because there was too few memory available (we usually had 90%, or 900MB free), but because due to **heap fragmentation** there wasn't one single contiguous block of memory that could be used of this array.

We ended up creating a `Blob` class which internally stored the data as chunks of chained (List) smaller **arrays**. The arrays had a fixed size (essential for quick lookups, so you can quickly calculate the involved array and offset for a given index), and we create `InputStream` and `OutputStream` classes for this Blob. Later we extended it to be swappable to and from the disk.

- Downside? None, apart from a little simple programming effort.
- Benefits? Efficient storage of large data in memory, no more problems
  with heap fragmentation.

I can only encourage you to give it a go!

Comment: Sounds like your application might benefit from memory-mapped files too. Start from `FileOutputStream.getChannel()` and `FileChannel.read(ByteBuffer)`. The mapped portions of your file can be accessed almost as fast as an direct array, without consuming any Java Heap space. This scales well, the Java GC won't be so burdened, and your app may "play nicer" with other software on the system.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard library has both a vector class (like a Java ArrayList) and a deque class (another List like class). The latter provides efficient prepending and efficient appending. The implementation I've seen maintained a list of blocks of fixed length arrays. So, somewhat like the case that interests you. So, this is certainly possible.

The downside is the greatly increased complexity of the code. I guess that the implementation in the JRE could be changed to do what you suggest, with the toByteArray method gathering data from the fragments. But doing this would be very low priority becae the simple implementation is blindingly fast. Any code doing IO should assume that reading and writing are slow operations, which can block. The ByteArrayOutputStream is instead very fast because it performs in memory operations instead of true external IO. Copying those byte arrays around is likely to be much faster than external IO. The downside of the current implementation is the creation of large garbage arrays, when used for large output streams. But the use cases for the class are for small streams; if you want to temporarily store the bytes of a large output stream, you should use a temporary file. So the complexity of your proposal would probably not help much in practice

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already know the benefits. Downsides of a list of buffers compared to a single buffer include:

- if the buffers are of fixed size, you need O(n) memory allocations to write n bytes, ByteArrayOutputStream makes O(log n) because buffer grows exponentially
- implementation is more complicated: you have to keep track of the active buffer, may need to switch buffers in the middle of a write (depending on design)
- switching buffers is a cache miss when reading

You are free to write such a data structure if it makes sense for your application

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be no real implementation I have quickly written a initial implementation to test the speed:

```
public class Buffer {

    private int size;

    private int writeIndex, writeOffset,
        readIndex, readOffset;

    private List<byte[]> backingArrays = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    public Buffer() {
        this(10240);
    }

    public Buffer(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int read(byte [] bytes) {
        return read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }

    public int read(byte [] bytes, int offset, int length) {
        int read = 0;
        while(length > 0) {
            byte [] input = getInput();
            // no more data
            if (input == null) {
                if (read == 0)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return read;
            }
            int readLength = Math.min(length, (readIndex == writeIndex ? writeOffset : size) - readOffset);
            System.arraycopy(input, readOffset, bytes, offset, readLength);
            length -= readLength;
            offset += readLength;
            readOffset += readLength;
            read += readLength;
        }
        return read;
    }

    public void write(byte [] bytes) {
        write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }

    public void write(byte [] bytes, int offset, int length) {
        while (length > 0) {
            byte [] output = getOutput();
            int writeLength = Math.min(length, output.length - writeOffset);
            System.arraycopy(bytes, offset, output, writeOffset, writeLength); 
            length -= writeLength;
            offset += writeLength;
            writeOffset += writeLength;
        }
    }

    private byte[] getOutput() {
        // if we have filled an array, move to the next one
        if (writeOffset >= size) {
            writeIndex++;
            writeOffset = 0;
        }
        // create it if it doesn't exist yet
        if (backingArrays.size() <= writeIndex)
            backingArrays.add(new byte[size]);

        return backingArrays.get(writeIndex);
    }

    private byte [] getInput() {
        // nothing written yet
        if (backingArrays.size() == 0)
            return null;

        if (readOffset >= size) {
            readIndex++;
            readOffset = 0;
        }
        // can not read past where it is written
        if (readIndex > writeIndex || (readIndex == writeIndex && readOffset >= writeOffset))
            return null;
        else
            return backingArrays.get(readIndex);
    }

    public long size() {
        return (long) size * (long) writeIndex + writeOffset;
    }
}
```

I'm testing it by copying a 36 meg file. A lot of course depends on the file interaction but in general it seems 40% faster in read slightly faster to write than bytearrayinputstream (hovered around 5-20% increase)

I put this together quickly so if you catch any bugs, let me know.

**EDIT**:

Added a feature that by default arrays that have been read are released for gc